# Java - condicion if cuando no se deben cumplir varias opciones

Tags: java, condiciones

Estoy teniendo problemas para que se ejecute una parte del código y no sé cuál es el error que estoy cometiendo.

El método lo que hace es calcular el valor de un coche en función del precio inicial, los años, el kilometraje y la transmisión (que sólo puede ser automática = 'A' o manual = 'M')

El código es el siguiente:

```
public static double calculateValuation(double price, int mileage, int age, char transmission) {
        double price_valuation, value_mileage, value_transmission, value_age;
        if (price<0 || mileage<0 || age<0){
            System.out.println("Price, mileage and age must be a positive number");
            System.out.println("-1");
        }
        if (transmission !='A' || transmission!='M'){
            System.out.println("Trasmission must be: 'A' or 'M'");
            System.out.println("-1");
        }

        value_mileage = calculateValuationByMileage(price, mileage);
        value_transmission = calculateValuationByTransmission(price, transmission);
        value_age = calculateValuationByAge(price, age);

        price_valuation = value_mileage + value_transmission + value_age;
        return price_valuation; 
}
```

Me aparece un warning en la línea de código `if (transmission !='A' || transmission!='M')`

Mi intención es indicar qué debe hacer el programa si **el valor introducido no es 'A' o no es 'M'**.
Cómo debo hacerlo?

Los métodos *calculateValuationByMileage(price, mileage)*, *calculateValuationByTransmission(price, transmission)* y *calculateValuationByAge(price, age)*
calculan un valor en base a porcentajes según el valor numérico de entrada.

El método que muestro, calcula el valor final en base a todos ellos como se puede apreciar.

Qué debo cambiar para poder corregirlo?

Muchas gracias.

Saludos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que tú quieres es que sea A o M. Es decir que ese mensaje debe mostrarse sólo cuando NO sea A Y NO sea M. Es decir:

```
if (transmission !='A' && transmission != 'M') {
```

En su versión actual, ese condicional siempre es verdadero porque, incluso cuando sea A, no va a ser M y viceversa.